# Invariant violation text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, npm, pie-chart

I am new to react-native development.
Whenever I try to use any framework I am getting error

> Invariant violation text strings must be rendered within a Text
>   component

I tried two libs [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) and for pichart [react-minimal-pie-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-minimal-pie-chart)

I know there are many questions already asked and I tried all but all are about syntax issue so I had to ask as I think it's not related to syntax as there is no any white space in code.

code as per below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format"
import PieChart from react-minimal-pie-chart

export default class Calculation extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };

  render() {
     return (
          <View>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgray", height: 1, marginHorizontal: 5 }} />
            <NumberFormat displayType="text" thousandSeparator={true} thousandsGroupStyle="lakh" prefix={'₹'} value={123456789} />

            <PieChart
              data={[
                { title: 'One', value: 10, color: '#E38627' },
                { title: 'Two', value: 15, color: '#C13C37' },
                { title: 'Three', value: 20, color: '#6A2135' },
              ]}
            />
          </View>

        );
    }
}
```

react-native version is `"0.60.5"`.

For reference I've attached screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: wondering.. is the library `react-minimal-pie-chart` react-native compatible ?

Comment: are you using expo or create-react-native-app ? Also can you please post the code of whole component and also where you are using it?

Comment: @AtinSingh I am using creat-react-native-app. and I am updating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay ... So upon seeing your code i didn't see anything wrong with it. So I went and checked the source code of the two of the libraries that you have used.

Both the libraries that you have used are not compatible with react-native as they are made for react js that is for browser as they use dom elements like `<div>` and `<input />`

Like take react-number-format for example the main number_format.js from src returns

```
return (
  <input
    {...inputProps}
    ref = {getInputRef}
  />
)
```

So, unfortunately you can't use these libraries for react-native.

Answer (score 0):

This error arise when you write a text out of text scope. Text can be written only in text tags. The library which you have used might not be compatible and might render text outside the scope which is causing this issue.